# Use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n} x^{2 n}$ to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} n}=\log (2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the series given by

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n} x^{2 n}, x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

and let $0 \leq a<1$.

a) (**Solved**) Show that the series convergence uniformly on $[-a, a]$.

b) (**Solved**) Show that the sum function $f:[-a, a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differential, and also show the following:

$$
f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^{2}}, \quad x \in[-a, a]
$$

c) **(Unsolved)** Determine the sum function $f:[-a, a] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and use it to show

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} n}=\log (2)
$$

*My attempt of solving c)*

Determining the sum function is easy. It's

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2}\log{\left(1-x^2\right)}$$

Now I want to show this identity $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} n}=\log (2)$ using my sum function. First I will like to find $x$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 n} x^{2 n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} n}$. I do this by solving the following equations for $x$: $ \frac{1}{2 n} x^{2 n}= \frac{1}{2^{n} n}$. I get $x=2^{\frac{1-n}{2 n}}$. Inserting this value of $x$ in my sum function should give me the sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n} n}$ which is $\log (2)$. But it does obviously not because $x$ has $n$ in it, so $f(x=2^{\frac{1-n}{2 n}}) \neq \log{(2)}$.

Please be kind and tell my why I'm wrong.

Notice:  $\log$ is natural logarithm function with Euler's number asa base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x = 1/\sqrt{2}$, we get $$\frac{1}{2n} x^{2n} = \frac{1}{2^n 2n}.$$  Then just factor out the $1/2$; i.e., $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n n} = 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n 2n} = 2f(1/\sqrt{2}).$$

---

I see that my original post above was not clear enough.  Here is the full treatment.

We want to evaluate $$S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n n}.$$  We know that for $|x| < 1$, $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} x^{2n} = -\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1 - x^2\right).$$
To this end, $$\frac{S}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n 2n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n} 2^{-n}$$ which suggests setting $x^{2n} = 2^{-n}$ or $x^2 = 2^{-1}$ or $x = 2^{-1/2} = 1/\sqrt{2}$ will give the desired result, namely $$\frac{S}{2} = f(1/\sqrt{2}).$$

Comment: @Xenusi I did not make any typos.

Comment: What does "To this end" mean?

Comment: Not to be bothersome. But what was wrong with my way of thinking?

Comment: @Xenusi By equating the summands directly, without an appropriate scaling factor, you are unable to select a value of $x$ that is independent of the index of summation $n$.  This is why your method fails, because $x$ must not be allowed to vary with $n$.  "To this end" means, "To achieve our goal," or "To accomplish this task."  The task to accomplish is "We want to evaluate $S$."

Comment: Thank! That is a pretty good explanation!